# Secure storage of SSH keys into Windows for use with C# to communicate with a Linux machine

Tags: c#, encryption, ssh, rsa

I'm working on a C# / WPF line-of-business application that needs to communicate securely with some remote systems that use SSH. I want to use public key authentication over SSH v2 in order to do this. I've already got a particular library in mind, but I need to know the best way to securely store my SSH keys in Windows and access them in C#. What are the best practices for going about this ? I've seen that [there exists RSA key containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but they seem to be associated with ASP.NET. I assume these can be used generically for any .NET application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping your sensitive information in [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx), its configurable, you have programmatic access, and easy to work with from within .net.

Comment: The documentation for isolated storage here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.100).aspx indicates that isolated storage should not be used to storage high value secrets (e.g. encryption keys). I can only assume then that I'll have to use the Data Protection API or something else in conjunction with IsolatedStorage ? Does Windows not have a built-in mechanism for storing various kinds of encryption information ?

Comment: It does, in a number of ways. If you want your own little file system that moves with the user across domain computers, etc, isolated storage is good, since its in the user profile and can be set to move with the roaming account. Theres EFS if you want to go full bore and encrypt the bits on disk, theres the DPAPI if you want to encrypt things specific to certain scopes, such as encrypted by user scope or by computer scope. 
If you are just looking for a way to protect the content while on disk you would probably do something custom with the DPAPI, perhaps in conjunction with iso. storage.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I'll look into the latter option.